# collocation - write a diary?

Tags: collocations

Is "write a diary" natural English? Many teachers say it is incorrect, but the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English online gives the following collocation:

> keep/**write a diary** (=write regularly in a diary) While I was travelling, I kept a diary every day.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/diary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Write a diary" seems perfectly normal, and there is plenty of usage:

> I'm convinced people tell the truth when they write a diary, *The Independent*
>
> Why I'd never write a diary. (Lucy Mangan in *The Guardian*)

But see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438479/keep-a-diary-take-a-diary-write-a-diary) on our sister site, that finds "Keep a diary" is much more common.

Note that you "write a diary entry" to refer to one day.